# how to upload file line by line to google cloud storage in java (Implementation of PipedInputStream)

Tags: java, file-io, google-cloud-storage

I am writing a java method in order to avoid keeping huge files in memory when I upload them to GCS, I am following what was done in [how to upload file line by line to google cloud storage in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510128/how-to-upload-file-line-by-line-to-google-cloud-storage-in-java/58847786#58847786)

I wonder how to do assignation of PipedInputStream used there. Could it be from from another srtream? I am trying with a connection to an PipedOutputStream, but a can't manage to get the entire line from a file:

```
// previosly I stream lines in fileInputStream. Obtaining a variable named line 

PipedInputStream inputStream = new PipedInputStream();
PipedOutputStream outputStream = new PipedOutputStream();

try {
    inputStream.connect(outputStream);
    outputStream.write(line.getBytes());

   System.out.println("INPUT STREAM READING: " + (char)inputStream.read());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Am I using Piped streams correctly? Had not done that before.

Comment: Your code doesn't work. What is `line`?

Comment: @Andrés Moreno Giraldo, could you please elaborate a little more about your code? Is there a chance that you can share more?